# C++ template class error with operator '<=>' (error C2678)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, c++20, spaceship-operator

I'm attempting to make a treap class in C++. I have the .h and .cpp files for this class, as well as a test class. My 'add' method gives me the following error when I attempt to build it: "error C2678: binary '<=>': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'E' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"

Here's my code:

Treap.h

```
#pragma once
#include <compare>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <stack>

template<class E>
class Treap
{
public:
    class Node {
    public:
        // data fields
        E data; // key for the search
        int priority; // random heap priority
        Node* left;
        Node* right;

        // omitted constructor for brevity


        // omitted rotation methods for brevity
    };

private:
    // data fields
    Node* root;

    // methods

    // omitted reheap method for brevity

public:
    // omitted constructors for brevity

    // omitted methods for brevity
};
```

Treap.cpp

```
#include "Treap.h"

template<class E>
bool Treap<E>::add(E& key, int priority) {
    Node* newNode = new Node(key, priority);
    if (root == nullptr) {
        root = newNode;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        // if key is found in tree, return false

        std::stack<Node*> nodeStack;
        Node* current = root;
        Node* prev = nullptr;
        auto n = current->data <=> key;
        nodeStack.push(current);
        while (n != 0 && current != nullptr) {
            prev = current;
            if (n > 0)
                current = current->left;
            else
                current = current->right;

            if (current == nullptr)
                break;

            nodeStack.push(current);
            n = current->data <=> key;
        }
        if (n > 0)
            prev->left = newNode;
        else
            prev->right = newNode;

        // omitted method that reheaps the treap
    }
    return true;
}
```

TreapTest.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include "../Treap.cpp"

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace TreapTest {
    TEST_CLASS(TreapTest) {
    public:
        TEST_METHOD(addTest) {
            Treap<std::string> test;
            Assert::IsTrue(test.add(std::string("p"), 99)); // this seems to be the line causing the issue
        }
    };
}
```

The lines that cause the errors are lines 13 and 26 (aka the lines with the spaceship operator).
I'm using VS 2019 and the C++ language standard is C++20. 
P.S.: I'm a newbie to C++. I'm converting my existing Java code to C++ as an exercise to understand and learn C++.

Edit: OK, I made some of the changes suggested by @cdhowie and @interjay. But none of those suggestions helped make this specific issue go away (which I somewhat expected since the code compiles without the test file in the solution, meaning that the original code compiles just fine despite my dumb mistakes).

Also, @Barry, I hope these updates better suit that standard.

Comment: A few things: (1) `Node` doesn't need to be a template; it already has access to the outer `E`. `Tree<std::string>::Node` and `Tree<int>::Node` would already be different types. `Tree<int>::Node<int>` is redundant. (2) `Node::data` should have type `E` and not `E&`. If you add a temporary like you do in your test, the temporary ceases to exist on the next line and the node is then referencing an object that no longer exists.

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong with this code that have nothing to do with the spaceship operator (for example, a constructor that doesn't initialize a reference member). Make sure to fix the errors in the order reported by your compiler, as later errors may just be derivative of the earlier ones.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @cdhowie OK, I've made all the changes that you suggested. However, this didn't end up fixing error C2678. If there's something else that I should have changed, let me know.

Comment: @interjay I also fixed the issue you brought up, but error C2678 persists.

Comment: @Chance Can you paste the full compiler output? My suspicion is that MSVC doesn't support everything in the C++20 draft yet.